# Реализация операции редукции для заданного массива для произвольной операции

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Грубо говоря, есть массив чисел, для него нужно выполнить на С++ многопоточно произвольную операцию (сумму элементов, произведение, поиска максимума итд итп). Как реализовать алгоритм редукции более менее понятно. Там делим массив на количество потоков, выполняем операцию, потом снова делим и так пока не останется ответ. Не понимаю только как можно реализовать универсальность?

Язык: С++11 thread (boost).

Вход: количество элементов в массиве и операция над массивом
Выход: результат операции над массивом.

Comment: Что вы понимаете по универсальностью? Один алгоритм для разных операций? Если применить функтор - годится?

Comment: Да, мне нужно сделать один алгоритм, для разных операций. Пока не представляю как функторы тут могут помочь.

Comment: Ну так у вас будет запускаться функция потока, в которую вы будете передавать матрицу, диапазон - так? А еще и функтор, который должен вернуть значение. И который, получив значения от запущенных функторов, обрабатывает и выдает, так сказать, резюме...

Comment: Мне кажется, не надо изобретать велосипед. Посмотрите в сторону OpenMP.

Comment: @alexolut Мне кажется, для начала надо посмотреть в сторону стандарта C++11 :)

Comment: @Harry зачем? чтобы заменить `boost::thread` на `std::thread`?

Comment: Чтобы сначала использовать стандартные средства. а уже потом openmp :) "Ну не люблю я его" (с)

Comment: Господа, прошу прощения, с++11 (да хоть 14) уже само собой разумеющееся. Поправил задачу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот, что-то такое на коленке набросал для вектора. Даже не использовал стандартные алгоритмы - но принцип, надеюсь, понятен? Если посидеть и подумать, можно, понятно, сделать и что-то покрасивее.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

const int minSize = 10000;

template<typename FuncFunc, typename FuncVec>
int handle(const vector<int>& v, int start, int end, FuncVec f, FuncFunc g)
{

    if (end - start < minSize)
    {
        return f(v,start,end);
    }
    int mid = (end+start)/2;
    future<int> f1 = async(handle<FuncFunc,FuncVec>,v,start,mid,f,g);
    future<int> f2 = async(handle<FuncFunc,FuncVec>,v,mid,end,f,g);
    return g(f1.get(),f2.get());
}


int sumVec(const vector<int>& v, int start, int end)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = start; i < end; ++i) sum += v[i];
    return sum;
}
int sumFunc(int v1, int v2)
{
    return v1+v2;
}

int maxVec(const vector<int>& v, int start, int end)
{
    int max = v[start];
    for(int i = start + 1; i < end; ++i) if (max < v[i]) max = v[i];
    return max;
}
int maxFunc(int v1, int v2)
{
    return (v1>v2) ? v1 : v2;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
        v.push_back(i);

    cout << "Calculate...\n";
    // Для проверки - вывод суммы/максимума, полученные однопоточно
    cout << "sum = " << sumVec(v,0,v.size()) << endl;
    cout << "sum = " << handle(v,0,v.size(),sumVec,sumFunc) << endl;
    cout << "max = " << maxVec(v,0,v.size()) << endl;
    cout << "max = " << handle(v,0,v.size(),maxVec,maxFunc) << endl;
}
```

P.S. Только понятно, что для такой задачи, пожалуй, быстрее считать однопоточно, чем вот так - многопоточно :)

Comment: Общий принцип твоего примера понятен. Но боюсь это несколько не то, что хотелось бы. Так, под каждую операцию нужно пилить свою функцию. Вот сверху предлагали вариант решения с функтором. Я думаю стоит туда копать. Но в любом случае, респект и уважуха.